# почему не работает Ctrl + Z? Как определить конец файла?

Tags: c

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
FILE *TF19_1, *TF19_2;
int i;
char ctrlz = 0x1A;
char str[SIZE], word;
if(!(TF19_1=fopen("TF19_1. txt", "wt"))){
    perror("File opening error");
    getch();
    return 0; }
   while(!feof(TF19_1)){
            if(gets(str))
        fputs(str, TF19_1);
    }
 fclose (TF19_1);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: feof не читает файл. Но посмотрите на логику - у Вас есть не конец файла, то в него пишем. Очень странно.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: Символом конца файла Ctrl/Z является только в винде. В люнихе - это Ctrl/D

Во-вторых: Именно поэтому, в программах на С рекомендуется использовать макрос EOF определённый в stdio.h

В-третьих: Модификатор открытия файла "t" среди стандартных я не обнаружитл.

В четвёртых: Имя открываемого файла содержит пробел. Так и надо, или это опечатка: "TF19_1. txt"

Ну и, наконец, по сути. Насколько я понимаю, Вам дали задание типа: "Копировать ввод с консоли в файл, пока не будет нажата комбинация EOF".

В таком случае, проверка на конец файла ВЫХОДНОГО файла *feof(TF19_1)* является полной бессмыслицей.

На самом деле надо проверять ввод. Как-то так:

```
while (gets(str) != NULL) {
    fputs(str, TF19_1);
}
```

Этот код тоже имеет недостатки, но пока рано про них говорить.